# Название класса и пространство имен имею одно и тоже имя

Tags: c#, .net, чистый-код

Допустим, у меня сборка содержит интерфейс и реализацию одного сервиса.

В итоге структура проекта выглядит так:

Dal->Models->SomeModel

Abstract->Services->ISomeService

Concreate->Services->SomeService

И хочется вот назвать сборку SomeService и корневым пространством имен сделать SomeService.

Все бы хорошо, но в других сборках приходится извращаться и писать полный путь к типу...

Вот как правильно выбирать пространство имен в таких случаях?

Answer (score 4):

Ну, во-первых, класть один сервис в одну сборку это как правило слишком сильно переусложнять себе жизнь, но да, проблема понятна, тоже сталкивался с таким.

А во-вторых, решение простое: вместо того, чтобы корневым пространством имён сделать SomeService вам нужно назвать его Contracts (там где вы говорите об Abstract->Services->ISomeService), мы такие штуки отдельно собираем в пакеты на тимсити, это логично и понятно - контракты на это, на то. И вот там уже не так критично, один интерфейс или сто в контракте - главное, что имя подбирается легче. Ну вот у нас допустим одно из типовых правил - это CompanyName.ProjectNameContracts или CompanyName.ProjectName.SomeContracts

С Concrete у меня как правило вообще вопрос такой не стоит - всё запихивается в проект с именем Application, обычно нет нужды делать более чем одной реализации, но чисто гипотетически я могу привести пример на реализацию в Ef, Dapper, Ado: примените префиксы Ef, Dapper, Ado перед названием своего сервиса. То есть найдите то, чем различаются у вас эти реализации и это сделайте префиксом. А если реализация у вас пока/всегда одна - тогда используйте слово Default в качестве префикса по умолчанию.

Итого, предлагаю например такой вариант: сборку называем SomeService, в ней делаем папки/неймспейсы Models, Contracts и DefaultImplementation. (Можно и другие варианты вывести, это вот то, что сразу просится)

Кроме того, я много смотрел примеров на Mediatr и мне даже чем-то нравится иногда то, что дописываешь имя неймспейса и через точку имя класса, вот например я у себя [экспериментировал](https://github.com/akmetainfo/WallyBackend/blob/master/src/Wally.WebApi/Controllers/TransactionController.cs):

один раз указан using:

```
using Transactions = Usol.Wally.Application.Transactions;
```

А потом в названиях пишем `Transactions.List.Query` или `Transactions.Create.Command` -- и это в принципе немного напоминает один из вариантов -- как если бы мы делали длинные уникальные имена тип `CreateCommand` или `CreateTransactionCommand`.

Так что иногда такие точки-разделители вполне нормально смотрятся, главное сгруппировать логично (у меня в этом примере сгруппировано не вокруг сервисов, а вокруг отдельных сущностей).

Answer (score 4):

Нужно руководствоваться Framework Design Guidelines:

[Names of Namespaces](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-namespaces)

> DO NOT use the same name for a namespace and a type in that namespace.

Да, всё верно, не называйте неймспейс и тип тем же именем.

Шаблон для именования оттуда же:

```
<Company>.(<Product>|<Technology>)[.<Feature>][.<Subnamespace>]
```

В вашем случае, имхо, фичей являются сервисы. Значит пространство имён может выглядеть как-то так:

```
namespace IluxaCorp.IluxaProduct.Services
```

Внутри него определены интерфейсы, классы и подпространства моделей.